# Vim: 100+ character length search query causes crash

Tags: search, vim, command-line

In the gVim Search window ("q/"), my screen can fit 100 characters before wrapping the line.  (This is apart from the text-wrapping setting in the main editing window.)  In building a complex search query (that I would later plug into a command statement) it locks up gVim when I try to run it - which only occurs if the query line wraps within this window.  There appears to be nothing in the line I wrote that was out of the ordinary.  My first sign that something might be wrong was when I saw gVim's automatically placed pre "/" (before the search query sentence within the Search Window) was added to the wrapped portion of the query line - but, obviously, I am not sure that's the issue.

Has anyone else experienced difficulty in developing long search queries in gVim?  I'm running 7.3 (w/patches 1-35) on a Ubuntu Natty system.

I realize I can break this line apart into smaller functions, but I was almost done doing it this way and would be interested in discovering a solution - if there is one.

Comment: I suspect adding the query you use would be useful.

Comment: I'm kind of horrified to know what you could be searching for that needs more than 100 characters...

Comment: @WayneWerner: Java method name, maybe (/me ducks). I tried a 233-character trivial search and it worked for me... And it wrapped not once but twice.

Comment: 1. I didn't know about `q/`, thank you. 2. I'm also curious about what kind of search it is that you make.

Comment: I have about 100 documents each of which is about 2,500 lines of text.  From each doc I am pulling pertinent information about groups (names, addresses, officers, meeting times, etc etc.  About 30 pieces of information per group and there's about 150 groups per document. The good news is that when you pick out one group - if done correctly - you'll get all the other groups (and documents) as well.  In that context, a 100+ character search query that saves to the registers and then substitutes back in the csv format needed for uploading into a website database is not excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use a regular vim script/buffer to assign search patterns

One 'simple' approach:

1. open a (new) buffer
2. type the search pattern as you would in the search window, on a single long line
3. do the following command to set the searchpattern as into the search register:

   ```
   :let @/=getline('.')
   ```

This has the same effect as pressing enter inside the Search Window, **except** for the fact that

- the cursor won't jump to the first match
- the pattern won't be recorded in the search history (effectively avoiding your crash)

There are a number of variation on this basic theme. The essence of which is: assign your search pattern directly into `@/`

Comment: My issue is evolving into a more 'complex' approach, but this is helpful (common sense and applicable).  Thank you.